# Woocommerce content layout issues

Tags: php, wordpress, commerce

So I have entered the correct code into my custom theme to be able to make it compatible with woo commerce, however, I'm unsure on how to style the content i.e. the product page wth all the products in columns. It's essentially in an unstyled ugly list. Can anyone assist in helping me setup woocommerce so that I can style it as I want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to copy the templates from within the woocomerce default theme to your theme's directory and modify them to suit your needs.